# Find missing mysql database on Xampp

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am running a WordPress website locally on Xampp server. I am trying to copy its database to be able to migrate the website but I can't find it in Phpmyadmin and neither in Xampp shell. The website works normally on localhost so I believe the database is there.

So far I tried:

1. Login as root and also with the wp database username from xampp shell and command Showdatabases which returns only information_schema.
2. Migrate the website as it is automatically using all in one wp migration. The plugins are installed when I do this but no pages/styles or plugin configuration
3. Restarted Xampp multiple times still no luck.

Some details about my configuration

1. Server running on Xampp
2. Os Windows 10
3. Website build on WordPress using Divi as a theme and I am running a child theme

Comment: Did you open `wp-config.php` to check the database connexion config ?

Comment: Yes. Also logged in from Xampp shell with the database username defined in wp-config but problem persists

Comment: When you're connecting using the settings from wp-config, make sure you also are using the same connection method (controlled with the host name). If wp-config is connecting to 'localhost', that user account is generally different than the same username connecting via an IP address or hostname.